# Magnetic force acting on a current loop while next to a current carrying wire

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, electrical-engineering

[image: Problem]

With I1=20A and I2=30A, find the net magnetic force acting on the loop.

I am not sure how to even approach this problem. I know that the magnetic field of the wire is $\frac{\mu_0I}{2\pi r}$ and that the magnetic force is $I_2\int_cd\vec{l}\times\vec{B}$ but I don't know how to put them together I suppose, or if those are even the appropriate equations to use.

I guess if they are, my biggest issue is finding what the differential length is and doing that cross product inside an integral. This whole topic is just very confusing for me.

Comment: *my biggest issue is finding what the differential length is and doing that cross product inside an integral* You’re on the right track. What difficulty are you having with those tasks?

Comment: This is a homework-like problem and someone isn’t going to solve it for you. You’ll have to ask a specific question about a concept that you don’t understand. Saying that “the whole topic is just very confusing” is too broad and unspecific. Here’s a hint: Calculate the force on the four sides separately. On the upper edge, $d\vec\ell$ is $dr\,\hat r$, but on the bottom edge it is $-dr\,\hat r$. By the way… kudos on your facility with MathJax!

Comment: Haha thank you, I take notes in Obsidian so MathJax is very standard for me to use.
Allow me to be more specific, I did not understand how to calculate the differential length because I didn't consider using r as the variable. I see how you found the top and bottom edges, but could you give a hint for the left and right edges? The magnetic field should be constant for the entire length top-to-bottom so would it be 0 (since r is also constant)?

Comment: I suggest using cylindrical coordinates. The left and right edges will be in the $z$-direction, so you should be able to figure out $d\vec\ell$ there.

Comment: Why would the magnetic field be zero? You already said that it is $\mu_0I/2\pi r$. That’s not zero except at infinite $r$.

Comment: *I did not understand how to calculate the differential length because I didn't consider using r as the variable.* You don’t have to do it that way. You could also use Cartesian coordinates.

Comment: Ah okay. I didn't consider using cylindrical coordinates. The issue of how to do a cross product in that coordinate system arises now. I thought since the two vectors just have one component, it would be a simple multiplication with it pointing in a new, orthogonal direction. This could still be right but I did not get the desired answer of $-\hat{x}0.4$. I attempted the solution with four integrals:

Comment: which combined into 2 with the reversed bounds and negative signs from the differential length substitutions;: $30\frac{20\mu_0}{2\pi}(2\int_{0}^{0.5}\frac{1}{r}\hat{r}dz+2\int_{0.1}^{0.3}\frac{1}{r}\hat{z}dr)$

Comment: If you use the right-hand-rule for cross products to determine the direction of the force on the top and bottom segments, you should find that the force is upward on the top and downward on the bottom, cancelling out any vertical force.

Comment: That leaves your first integral, which doesn’t make sense because what value is $r$ supposed to have?

Comment: Oh my mistake, I actually did the "first" integral properly on paper by having it still as two integrals. Then the value of r was 0.1 for one and 0.3 for the other. Then when I was writing it out here I incorrectly combined them for brevity